# How do I use dependency injection for external dependencies?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, dependencies

I think I almost got this.

Say I want my app to send SMSs. But Im not sure yet if I should go with Twilio or SomeOtherSMSService. In fact, I dont really care yet. So I have something as simple as this so I could keep developing my app.

```
public interface ISMSService{
    public bool SendMessage(string to, string message);
}
```

now I want to try Twilio. This is where I get confused. I can install it as a Nuget package but I dont think their C# wrapper that uses their REST API is going to match my interface at all.. and modifying it doesnt seem a good idea either.

from the readme I can see that to use it I need to do something like this

```
var msg = twilio.SendSmsMessage("+15551112222", "+15553334444", "Can you believe it's this easy to send an SMS?!");
```

And my best guess is that I should WRAP this into my own implementation of the interface. 
Something like this.

```
using Twilio;

public TwilioSMSService : ISMSService
{
    TwilioRestClient twilio;
    public TwilioSMSService()
    {
        twilio = new TwilioRestClient("accountSid", "authToken");

    }

    public bool SendMessage(string to, string message)
    {
        var msg = twilio.SendSmsMessage("+15551112222", to, message);
        if (msg != null) return true;
        return false;
        // this would obviously need more logic.
    }
```

I want to make sure that Im keeping dependency injection principle with this but it seems fishy to me that I need to instantiate TwilioRestClient in the default constructor which is exactly what dependency injection i supposed to help you avoid :s .

Is this approach correct? If not how would you do it?

Please Help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's perfectly acceptable. You are abstracting the dependency of `TwilioRestClient` away from the consuming class. That way you can in your controllers toss in a `FakeSMSService` for unit testing. You shouldn't need to unit test Twilio.

Comment: perfect. I just wanted to make sure that instantiating te TwilioClient object inside the constructor wasnt wrong.. thank you.

Comment: You might consider putting it in a try/catch. That way it won't have a huge impact if it throws an exception.

Comment: Jamie, but how i can inject that? I have no control over that.I cant have it implement an interface that I can configure to get injected.

Comment: But shouldn't a unit test for `TwilioSMSService` still be written though? And now it will be harder to write such a unit test because the class `TwilioRestClient ` is hardcoded. Is there a way to somehow still hook into the services of the startup class to inject `TwilioRestClient` as well?

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good write-up on this on the twillio blog, we are not using mvc controllers for our project so we cannot use it but sharing the link in case it helps you out.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/adding-dependency-injection-to-your-asp-net-mvc-twilio-app-using-mef.html

Article was a bit over my head but it looks useful.